# Which of the following involves context switch?

Tags: process, operating-system, context-switch

Which of the following involves context switch?

A. System Call

B. Privileged Instruction

C. Both A & B

D. None Of These

Comment: Are you taking a test on Stack Overflow?

Comment: In my opinion answer should be C. But [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call#Processor_mode_and_context_switching) system call does not necessarily involves context switch.

Comment: I'm not taking any test. I want to just discuss this question with others.

Comment: Care to provide some context for this question?

Answer (score 1):

D. None of these

A system call involves a mode switch (user mode to kernel mode) but does not *necessarily* mean a context switch (this depends on OS): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch

Since A isn't true, D is the only remaining option

(My intuition would tell me that a privileged instruction would require you to already be in kernel mode)

Answer (score 0):

Both A and B.

When a system call is executed a context switch between user space to kernel space has to take place.

When a priority task is executed the thread or process context needs to switch to perform the priority task by switching from the task that was currently being executed.

Comment: But [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call#Processor_mode_and_context_switching) it is given that system call does not necessarily involves context switch.

Comment: You can find an exception to every rule.